# wrong matter.js velocity on phaser.js object

Tags: phaser-framework, matter.js

I'm trying to move an object from one side of the screen to the other side using Phaser.js (v 3.6) with physics by Matter.js.

I'm trying to do it with the `setVelocity` method of `Physics.Matter.Sprite` (in a derived class of `Physics.Matter.Sprite`) like this:

```
this.setVelocity(10, 0);
```

But the speed doesn't seem right.
As far as I understand, Matter.js uses the 1 pixel = 1 meter ratio, so I guess it should move 10px per second. It moves across the screen in about 2 seconds.
I'm using the mobile simulator of chrome for pixel5 so the screen width should be about 390px.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, I can only assume, it has to do with the **air-friction**.
*(by default it is set to 0.01 [link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Types.Physics.Matter.html#.MatterBodyConfig__anchor))*

Try using `this.setFrictionAir(0);`, this sets air-friction to zero ([link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Matter.Components.Friction.html#setFrictionAir__anchor)).

> *If the object touches the ground you might have to set friction also to zero, for at you can use the funciton `setFriction(...)`.*

Comment: I already set the air friction to 0...

Comment: well without seeing more code, or a more detailed description of the issue, I can't help. Maybe someone else has some ideas.

Comment: btw.: pixel 5 hast a pixel ratio of 2.75, bit as far as I know chrome Simulator has/had the pixel ratio of the pc ot os running on. maybe this could be the source of the Problem.

Comment: I think I found out the problem. It's not moving the object at 10px per pixel but in 10px PER FRAME!!! :)